# Bitbucket OAuth2 using Node.js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, bitbucket

I want to have a capability in my application that allows users to Authorize Bitbucket. I have followed https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html.

The following works and brings the Bitbucket authorization screen as expected:
https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code

However, this part emits an error about invalid Grant.

```
$ curl -X POST -u "client_id:secret" \
  https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code={code}
```

I am using `request` module in Node.js and using the code as follows:

```
request.post(
  'https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token',
  {
     json: {
         client_id: config.get('app.bitbucket_client_id'),
         client_secret: config.get('app.bitbucket_client_secret'),
         code: req.query.code,
         grant_type: "authorization_code"
        }
      }, function (error, response, body) {    
         // Do something here
      }
  }
```

{"result":{"error_description":"Unsupported grant type: None","error":"invalid_grant"}}

Please advice!

Comment: isn't the error saying u haven't included the grant_type parameter in your request JSON?

Comment: What should it be?

If I add grant_type: "authorization_code" it complains...

{"result":{"error_description":"Unsupported grant type: None","error":"invalid_grant"}}

Comment: @RickLee I tried adding the grant_type, but the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my question. Basically, Bitbucket expects data to be sent in body directly instead of JSON. Changing from `json` to `form` in the code above fixed it for me.